# MS Access ODBC connection issue with php

Tags: php, odbc

Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied., SQL state 08001 in SQLConnect in C:\xampp\htdocs\Admin\index.php on line 9

Comment: Maybe the database is in use by you. Try close Access

Comment: make sure u have installed and configured MS access ODBC driver for the mdb